# Shiny App Time Series plot with data table

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a simply Shiny app, which can take data input from a CSV file and then display the data along with a plot, here is the R code that I have written,

```
require(graphics) 
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#This function is repsonsible for loading in the selected file
filedata <- reactive({
infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
# User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
      data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
      data
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath)

  })


  #This previews the CSV data file
  output$filetable <- renderTable({
    filedata()
  })

  #Plot time Series plot
  output$tsplot <- renderPlot({
    x <- as.numeric(filedata)
    ts.obj <- ts(x)
    lowess.obj <- lowess(ts.obj, f = 10)
    plot.ts(x, main = "Sample Time Series", xlab = "Time")
    points(x)
    lines(lowess.obj$y, col = "red")
    legend("top", legend = "Loess Smoother", col = "red", lty = 1)
  })
```

but when I run this I get an error 'ERROR : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'', not able to figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you shoud trying this :

```
 output$tsplot <- renderPlot({
        x <- as.numeric(filedata())### call the data file with parenthesis
        ts.obj <- ts(x)
        lowess.obj <- lowess(ts.obj, f = 10)
        plot.ts(x, main = "Sample Time Series", xlab = "Time")
        points(x)
        lines(lowess.obj$y, col = "red")
        legend("top", legend = "Loess Smoother", col = "red", lty = 1)
      })
```

Comment: when I try this, I get this Error '(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: the as.numeric() function work with vectors so you have to select which column of your input file you want to convert to numeric and work with it

Comment: @Vikram Could you show the code where you select the column of you input file? I tried several versions, but always get errors. Would be nice if you could specify the changes of line  x <- as.numeric(filedata())!